# How to call a function with types known at runtime

Tags: c++, c, reflection, runtime, shared-libraries

After loading a dynamic library and `GetProcAddress`, one typically get a function pointer of type `void*`. To call the function, when doing it at compile time, one would cast the pointer into the correct pointer type needed.

However, if the type is not known at compile time but at runtime instead, and there's many possibilities of the type. In this scenario, it seems one would need to "Call" the function manually, aka, update the stack and registers according to the ABI.

The question is: Is there any open source code that takes care of this in common platforms and ABI? If not, how do I implement one myself?

The Microsoft abi documentations have some things on the cdecl and other conventions, and it seems 32bit and 64bit are different. Is ABI on Linux the same or something else?

Comment: If the type is not known, it should probably be treated like a `void *`. You cannot do anything sensible with the return value unless you know what it is, or unless you pass it to a function that does. Generally, if you encounter this question, I think you may have a design issue. Updating the stack etc. is not the problem of a C developer. You shouldn't run into any trouble with that.

Comment: Could you provide an example where you run into this issue?

Comment: The ABI on Linux is different from the one used on Windows, you can see a table at the bottom of [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) (assuming you are talking about x86).

Comment: @Cheatah I know executing arbitrary code is dangerous, but suppose you want your user to use the command line to execute something s/he wrote and compiled into a dll, with the parameters given on the command line at runtime.

Comment: @Cheatah In this way, although the type information is missing in C decoration dll, one can still somehow use the functions inside without knowing at compile time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In another answer I said that https://dyncall.org/ looks to be what is needed.

That answer was deleted, despite comments saying it was correct. Re-posting the information here in case anyone else needs it.