# How to call a DLL method by c++ code besides using GetProcAddress

Tags: c++, windows, function, dll

Is there any windows api in c++ besides GetProcAddress that can call a DLL method?  For example, assume that the api's name is FUNC, we want to use it to call MessageBoxA in user32.dll, then we can write code like

```
FUNC("user32.dll", "MessageBoxA", 0, "this is text", "this is caption", 0)
```

So far I haven't found any api that can do it in this way.

in the beginning, I try to encapsulate GetProcAddress in my own function to achieve the above FUNC but find a problem: GetProcAddress returns the function pointer whose return type and parameters are fixed. Considering that the input for FUNC and the return for FUNC are not fixed, it's impossible to enumerate all the conditions. So I am curious if there is a existing api.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call a function with types known at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61677021/how-to-call-a-function-with-types-known-at-runtime)